# Image on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode5

I have an ImageView with a picture and a button centered within it. On the button I have a different UIImage and the background on the button is white. In Attributes Inspector I have selected the UIImage for the button and made the button custom but still I have white background on the button.

I want the background on the button to be the same as the picture on the ImageView. I thought it was enough to change the button to custom. I am using Xcode 5.0.2, is there anyone that could help me with this. This is what my ImageView + button looks like now:

[image]

And these are the settings for the button:

[image]

Comment: honestly it is not very clear .. post a screenshot or code

Comment: That's a long sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to make background for the button clear, from within the Attributes Inspector scroll down to the View section and change the background to `Clear Color` from the dropdown menu.

Also make sure your .png has a transparent background. If you've already set the background to Clear Color the issue could simply be that your .png has a white background rather than a clear one.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Add image that you use for ImageView to Background properties of your button.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do:

```
yourButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]]
```